# Ruby: parametrize string without Ruby on rails framework (Jekyll plugin)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll, jekyll-extensions, parametrize

I have plugin that takes attribute from post's front matter and uses it in permalink. Problem is I need to clean up any accents and diacritics from the string before putting it in to the permalink. Ruby on rails has method called [`parametrize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-parameterize) which does exactly what I need but I have no idea how to use it in plugin.

This is plugins code I have:

```rb
module JekyllCustomPermalink
  class CustomPermalink < Jekyll::Generator
    safe true
    priority :low

    def generate(site)
      # nothing to do, wait for hook
    end

    Jekyll::Hooks.register :documents, :pre_render do |doc|
      begin
        # check if jekyll can resolve the url template
        doc.url
      rescue NoMethodError => error
        begin
          if !doc.collection.metadata.fetch("custom_permalink_placeholders").is_a?(Array)
            raise CustomPermalinkSetupError, "The custom placeholders need to be an array! Check the settings of your '#{doc.collection.label}' collection."
          end
          def doc.url_template
            @custom_url_template ||= collection.metadata.fetch("custom_permalink_placeholders").inject(collection.url_template){|o,m| o.sub ":" + m, data[m].to_s.parameterize}
          end
        rescue KeyError
          # "custom_permalink_placeholders"
          raise CustomPermalinkSetupError, "No custom placeholders defined for the '#{doc.collection.label}' collection. Define an array of placeholders under the key 'custom_permalink_placeholders'. \nCaused by: " + error.to_s
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

but I get this error:

```
john@arch-thinkpad ~/P/blog (master)> bundle exec jekyll serve --trace
Configuration file: /home/john/Projects/lyricall/_config.yml
            Source: /home/john/Projects/lyricall
       Destination: /home/john/Projects/lyricall/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
  Liquid Exception: undefined method `parameterize' for "Žďořšťáčik":String in feed.xml
bundler: failed to load command: jekyll (/home/john/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin/jekyll)
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll_custom_permalink-0.0.1/lib/jekyll_custom_permalink/custom_permalink.rb:20:in `block in url_template': undefined method `parameterize' for "Žďořšťáčik":String (NoMethodError)
```

What am I doing wrong ? How can I use this method which should be part of a string class but apparently it is not ? How can I achieve same result without ruby on rails framework ?

INFO:

- jekyll 4.1.1
- ruby 3.0.1p64 (2021-04-05 revision 0fb782ee38) [x86_64-linux]

Thank you for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails additions to base Ruby classes, like `String#parameterize`, are part of the [Active Support Core Extensions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#inflections). The `activesupport` gem can be installed and used independent of Rails.

To keep the default footprint low, ActiveSupport allows you to `require` only the individual extensions you want to use. In your case, you will need to require the string inflection extensions:

```rb
require 'active_support/core_ext/string/inflections'
"Kurt Gödel".parameterize 
=> "kurt-godel"
```